# Switch between Tabs with Applescript

Tags: applescript, cocoa

I have a cocoa-applescript application whose GUI interface has 3 tabs.The identifiers for these 3 tabs are "item 1" "item 2" and "item 3" respectively.

Tab1 is the default tab with a form on it. Tab 2 displays the results. When user submits a form on  tab1, I want the App to switch to Tab 2. How do I do this using applescript?

Comment: You don't provide enough information. AppleScript GUI Scripting requires the internal hierarchy of elements to be traversed. Can you give us partial source code?